# Percona XtraDB Cluster: How to skip SST when starting?

Tags: mysql, replication, percona, xtradb-cluster, xtradb

Is there a way to skip State Snapshot Transfer (SST) at startup on Percona XtraDB Cluster Server?

`wsrep_sst_mode=skip` doesn't work:

```
121003  6:49:55 Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 1.1.8-rel28.1 started; 
    log sequence number 82208067084
121003  6:49:55 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: unknown variable 'wsrep_sst_mode=skip'
121003  6:49:55 [ERROR] Aborting
```

I'm using Percona-XtraDB-Cluster-server-5.5.27-23.6.356.rhel5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want `wsrep_sst_method=skip` not `wsrep_sst_mode=skip`

```
mysql> show variables like 'wsrep_sst%';
+---------------------------+------------+
| Variable_name             | Value      |
+---------------------------+------------+
| wsrep_sst_auth            |            |
| wsrep_sst_donor           |            |
| wsrep_sst_method          | xtrabackup |
| wsrep_sst_receive_address | AUTO       |
+---------------------------+------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: You're right. Is [this](http://www.percona.com/webinars/2012-06-06-migrating-to-percona-xtradb-cluster) document wrong?

Comment: Yup, it's wrong. I have that same PDF from the Webinar. This is a guess, but maybe earlier versions of Galera may have had mode, or maybe it's just wrong.